# Jest: restore original module implementation on a manual mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a pretty common testing use case and I am not sure what's the best approach there.

### Context

I would like to **test a module that depends on a userland dependency**. The userland dependency (`neat-csv`) **exports a single function that returns a Promise**.

### Goal

I want to mock `neat-csv`'s behavior **so that it rejects with an error for one single test. Then I want to restore the original module implementation.**

AFAIK, I can't use `jest.spyOn` here as the module exports a single function.

So I thought using manual mocks was appropriated and it works. However I can't figure it out how to restore the original implementation over a manual mock.

### Simplified example

For simplicity here's a stripped down version of the module I am trying to test:

```
'use strict';

const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

async function convertCsvToJson(apiResponse) {
  try {
    const result = await neatCsv(apiResponse.body, {
      separator: ';'
    });
    return result;
  } catch (parseError) {
    throw parseError;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  convertCsvToJson
};
```

And here's an attempt of testing that fails on the second test (non mocked version):

```
'use strict';

let neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
let { convertCsvToJson } = require('./module-under-test.js');

jest.mock('neat-csv', () =>
  jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error while parsing'))
);

const csv = 'type;part\nunicorn;horn\nrainbow;pink';
const apiResponse = {
  body: csv
};

const rejectionOf = (promise) =>
  promise.then(
    (value) => {
      throw value;
    },
    (reason) => reason
  );

test('mocked version', async () => {
  const e = await rejectionOf(convertCsvToJson(apiResponse));
  expect(neatCsv).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(e.message).toEqual('Error while parsing');
});

test('non mocked version', async () => {
  jest.resetModules();
  neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
  ({ convertCsvToJson } = require('./module-under-test.js'));

  const result = await convertCsvToJson(apiResponse);
  expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toEqual(
    '[{"type":"unicorn","part":"horn"},{"type":"rainbow","part":"pink"}]'
  );
});
```

I am wondering if jest is designed to do such things or if I am going the wrong way and should inject neat-csv instead ?

What would be the idiomatic way of handling this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Jest *is* designed to do such things.

The API method you are looking for is [jest.doMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options). It provides a way of mocking modules without the implicit hoisting that happens with *jest.mock*, allowing you to mock in the scope of tests.

Here is a working example of your test code that shows this:

```
const csv = 'type;part\nunicorn;horn\nrainbow;pink';
const apiResponse = {
    body: csv
};

const rejectionOf = promise =>
    promise.then(value => {
        throw value;
    }, reason => reason);

test('mocked version', async () => {
    jest.doMock('neat-csv', () => jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Error while parsing')));
    const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
    const { convertCsvToJson } = require('./module-under-test.js');
    const e = await rejectionOf(convertCsvToJson(apiResponse));
    expect(neatCsv).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(e.message).toEqual('Error while parsing');
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

test('non mocked version', async () => {
    const { convertCsvToJson } = require('./module-under-test.js');

    const result = await convertCsvToJson(apiResponse);
    expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toEqual('[{"type":"unicorn","part":"horn"},{"type":"rainbow","part":"pink"}]');
});
```

Comment: I just had the opportunity to gave it a try but for some reasons this does not work. I don't use babel at all in my project. Does the doMock method works only when ones use babel-jest in the project ?

Comment: No, `doMock` is part of the Jest API, it has nothing to do with Babel. What's the error you are getting? What does "this does not work” mean exactly? 

Comment: I had actually set up a working version of the test on my local machine, so I'm confident the code from my answer works. It did for me.

Comment: I will dig further with this, might be an error on my side then. It seems that the module isn't using the mock at all and uses the original module implementation when I do use doMock at a test level scope

Comment: Ok I got what I was doing wrong, I was still importing the convertCsvToJson at the root level scope so It didn't had any idea that the neat-csv module could be mocked. Moving it after the mock fixes thing. Thank you very much for your  help !

Comment: I am wondering though that if the second test works for you as it ? It seems to me that the `module-under-test` require will fetch `convertCsvToJson` from cache and will fetch the one with the mocked `neat-csv` implementation. I had to add `jest.unmock('neat-csv')` and `jest.resetModules()` before the first line of the second test to have it to pass

Comment: It's possible that it only worked for me without reset modules because of a different jest version or something. If you use `jest.restoreAllMocks` after the first test, you don't have to use `unmock` or `resetModules`